# Записать в файл, весь отображаемый в консоли, в процессе выполнения программы (потока), текст

Tags: java, многопоточность, логирование, io

К примеру: один поток "общается" с пользователем. Выводит в консоль вопросы, пользователь отвечает, в зависимости от его ответов, получает некий результат. Второй поток пишет в файл все что отображается в консоли, в результате работы первого потока. С помощью чего реализовать? Логирование? Подскажите пример кода. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы так решил. 
Синглтон который можно вызывать везде со списком внутри и synchronize модификатор для поочередной записи со всех потоков. Когда насобирал контейнер то вызываешь get метод и записываешь в файл.

```
public class XXLog {

    private static XXLog xxLog = null;
    private static List<String> logContainer;

    static {
        if (xxLog == null) {
            xxLog = new XXLog();
            logContainer = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void addToLogContainer(String log) {
        logContainer.add(log);
    }

    public List<String> getLogContainer() {
        return logContainer;
    }
}
```

Вызов: `XXLog.addToLogContainer(log);`